# Find the value of resonance

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

Suppose a mechanical oscillator has movement denoted by $y$ and we have a particular solution to the differential equation $y'' + cy' + 4y = \cos(\omega t)$ as $y(t) = \frac{4}{\sqrt{(\omega^2 - 4)^2 + \omega^2}}\cos(\omega t - \phi)$

> Find the value of $\omega$ for which (if) any resonance is created.

So I understand that resonance is where the amplitude is the maximum, so we have to maximize

$\displaystyle f(\omega) = \frac{4}{\sqrt{(\omega^2 - 4)^2 + \omega^2}}$

I got $\omega = \sqrt{7/2}$, but is this right?

Or are we just supposed to solve the denominator for $0$?

Comment: Your frequency is presumably real, so the denominator of $f$ cannot be zero. $\sqrt{7/2}$ is indeed a maximum of $f$. So is $-\sqrt{7/2}$ by the way, but a negative frequency would seem odd for a mechanical oscillator.

Comment: Your frequency response looks wrong: it should involve $c$, the coefficient of the damping term.